# Open JSON value from one column which has more than one root into a table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

In SQL Server, I want to open a JSON which all are in different rows in one column also I have to mention that they have more than one root
My table (`RelationTBL`) is like :

| PersonCode | Relation |
| --- | --- |
| 961113021 | [{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sara"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}}] |
| 971113052 | [{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sana"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}},{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sara"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Son"}}] |

I wanted to open this JSON with `JSON_VALUE()`, but it does not work.

My code:

```
WITH temp AS
(
 SELECT PersonCode , Relation  
 FROM RelationTBL
 WHERE Relation IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT PersonCode , JSON_VALUE(VALUE,'$.Name')
FROM temp
```

My output 1:

| PersonCode | Name | Relation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 961113021 | Sara | Wife |
| 971113052 | Sana | Wife |
| 971113052 | Ben | Son |

My output 2:

| PersonCode | Name & Relation |
| --- | --- |
| 961113021 | (Sara , Wife) |
| 971113052 | (Sana , Wife), (Ben , Son) |

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *... they have more than one root*, because the stored JSON is a valid JSON array of JSON objects without multiple root items, so in this situation, an approach based on `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema and an `APPLY` operator is an option:

```
SELECT t.PersonCode, j.Name, j.Relation
FROM (VALUES
   ('961113021', '[{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sara"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}}]'),
   ('971113052', '[{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sana"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}},{"Name":{"Ben":"string","value":"Sara"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Son"}}]')
) t (PersonCode, Relation)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(t.Relation) WITH (
   Name varchar(100) '$.Name.value',
   Relation varchar(100) '$.Relation.value'
) j
```

Result:

```
PersonCode  Name    Relation
961113021   Sara    Wife
971113052   Sana    Wife
971113052   Sara    Son
```

If you really want to use `JSON_VALUE()`, use the following statement:

```
SELECT 
   t.PersonCode,
   JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Name.value') AS [Name],
   JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Relation.value') AS [Relation]
FROM (VALUES
   ('961113021', '[{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sara"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}}]'),
   ('971113052', '[{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sana"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}},{"Name":{"Ben":"string","value":"Sara"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Son"}}]')
) t (PersonCode, Relation)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(t.Relation) j
```

Comment: @SaraMoradi, If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.